# lambda nodejs error index.handler is undefined or not exported

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Getting following error when i run the nodejs lambda code.

"errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
"errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",

the folder structure is

```
audit_package
 - nodejs
    - node.js
```

The lambda handler name is  "index.handler"
runtime package is "nodejs12.x"

Dont pass any paramters while invoking lambda.

Here is the code

```
console.log('function starts');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    console.log('processing event: %j', event);

    let scanningParameters = {
        TableName: 'epro-audit-cert',
        Limit: 10 //maximum result of 100 items
    };

    //In dynamoDB scan looks through your entire table and fetches all data
    docClient.scan(scanningParameters, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: change your folder structure and file name as below and try.
audit_package
    - index.js

Answer (score 1):

This is working now. Moved index.js to root folder

Comment: where? in aws console?

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust your [handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html):

> Handler – The method that the runtime runs when your function is invoked, such as index.handler. The first value is the name of the file or module. The second value is the name of the method.

Since you have your file in `nodejs` folder, it should be:

```
nodejs/node.handler
```